# Will choosing whether to display a component in render() using props/state result in a redraw every time?

Tags: reactjs

Are the following two equivalent performance wise? Will the first example cause `Component1` and `Component2` to be re-rendered every time `MyComponent`'s props are updated?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { selectShowComponent1, selectShowComponent2 } from './selectors';

@connect(createStructuredSelector({
  showComponent1: selectShowComponent1,
  showComponent2: selectShowComponent2,
}))
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    showComponent1: React.PropTypes.bool,
    showComponent2: React.PropTypes.bool,
  };

  render() {
    const { showComponent1, showComponent2 } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {showComponent1 ? (<Component1>shown 1</Component1>) : ''}
        {showComponent2 ? (<Component2>shown 2</Component2>) : ''}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { selectShowComponent1, selectShowComponent2 } from './selectors';

@connect(createStructuredSelector({
  showComponent1: selectShowComponent1,
  showComponent2: selectShowComponent2,
}))
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    showComponent1: React.PropTypes.bool,
    showComponent2: React.PropTypes.bool,
  };

  render() {
    const { showComponent1, showComponent2 } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Component1 renderMe={showComponent1}>shown 1</Component1>
        <Component2 renderMe={showComponent2}>shown 2</Component2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: second approach will render both of components and just inside those components you will manage what to show. First approach, from the other hand, will mount new component every time something will change in your props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one will re-render every time, whereas the second one won't. The reason is dynamically generated components (in this case, dynamic cos they're the result of a ternary operator) get given a new key each time they're returned from the dynamic context. And this key is what React uses internally to uniquely identify components.

So I believe if you gave them explicit keys:

```
    {showComponent1 ? (<Component1 key="1">shown 1</Component1>) : ''}
    {showComponent2 ? (<Component2 key="2">shown 2</Component2>) : ''}
```

Then in theory that should stop them being re-rendered, but that's not ideal as manually assigning keys in some scenarios may mean the component may not re-render when you actually want it to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The keys, are they "scoped" within each component? Could I get conflicts if I use the same keys in multiple components? ie, if I have a list in the header component and the keys for the items are 1, 2, 3, ... and then another list in the footer with items assigned the same key values, will they conflict?

Comment: They only need to be unique with regard to their siblings (i.e. the level below their parent).